# BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000081b66158 (for 14.04 kernel:4.4.0-31)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

I got the following output using "log" command at the "crash" utility command-line:

```
[9176.888659] perf interrupt took too long (5011 > 5000), lowering  kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000. 
[92733.329430] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000081b66158  
[92733.329496] IP: [<0000000081b66158>] 0x81b66158. 
[92733.329533] PGD 1057674067 PUD 0   
[92733.329561] Oops: 0010 [#1] SMP    
[92733.329589] Modules linked in: ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4   nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack iptable_filter xt_tcpudp xt_CT nf_conntrack iptable_raw ip_tables x_tables intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ipmi_devintf ipmi_ssif bonding ablk_helper cryptd dm_multipath sb_edac edac_core 8250_fintek shpchp lpc_ich mac_hid acpi_power_meter ipmi_si ipmi_msghandler iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid0 multipath linear raid1 ast ttm drm_kms_helper mxm_wmi syscopyarea ixgbe sysfillrect igb vxlan sysimgblt ip6_udp_tunnel fb_sys_fops dca udp_tunnel ptp drm ahci pps_core i2c_algo_bit. 
[92733.330174]  libahci mdio fjes wmi.  
[92733.330198] CPU: 24 PID: 24797 Comm: java Not tainted 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu.  
[92733.330250] Hardware name: Quanta Computer Inc. P-100.Scaler.01/S2PC-MB(Dual 1G LOM), BIOS S2P_3B04.HGT04 04/12/2017.  
[92733.330316] task: ffff88104aa7ee00 ti: ffff88104c940000 task.ti: ffff88104c940000.  
[92733.330364] RIP: 0010:[<0000000081b66158>]  [<0000000081b66158>] 0x81b66158.  
[92733.330411] RSP: 0018:ffff88104c943d50  EFLAGS: 00010246.  
[92733.330445] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff88104c943dc0 RCX: 0000000000000013.  
[92733.330490] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 000000007a3e56da.  
[92733.330536] RBP: ffffffff8137c2b8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: ffffc90007b4d6e0.  
[92733.330581] R10: 000000002b300067 R11: 0000000000000067 R12: ffffffff8173f1cb.  
[92733.330626] R13: 000000000000fe88 R14: ffff88104c943e30 R15: 0000000000000025  
[92733.330671] FS:  00007f93e36f6700(0000) GS:ffff88105f400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000.   
[92733.330723] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033.  
[92733.330760] CR2: 0000000081b66158 CR3: 000000104f5d4000 CR4: 00000000003406e0.  
[92733.330806] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000.  
[92733.330851] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400.  
[92733.330895] Stack:  
[92733.330911]  ffff880707f74600 ffff88104aa7ee00 ff01ffff00000000 0000000000000025.  
[92733.330965]  ffff880b00000000 000005a800000000 0000000000000025 ffffffff0000fe88.  
[92733.331019]  7fffffffffffffff ffff880b7dd618c0 ffff880707f74600 0000000000000000.  
[92733.331073] Call Trace:  
[92733.331097]  [<ffffffff81769937>] ? inet_sendmsg+0x67/0xa0.  
[92733.331137]  [<ffffffff816d6d58>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x38/0x50.  
[92733.331174]  [<ffffffff816d71f2>] ? SYSC_sendto+0x102/0x190.  
[92733.331213]  [<ffffffff8137ccb4>] ? aa_sock_opt_perm+0x54/0x110.  
[92733.331254]  [<ffffffff8173d00c>] ? tcp_getsockopt+0x2c/0x30.  
[92733.331293]  [<ffffffff816d7d3e>] ? SyS_sendto+0xe/0x10.  
[92733.331330]  [<ffffffff817f6f36>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75.   
[92733.331372] Code:  Bad RIP value.   
[92733.331397] RIP  [<0000000081b66158>] 0x81b66158.  
[92733.331429]  RSP <ffff88104c943d50>.  
[92733.331453] CR2: 0000000081b66158.
```

As per the kernel documentation at "kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html" section 4.6, it reads as folows :

> Fault occurred in the userspace region while in kernel mode   - Error - If a fault occurs, it means a kernel system did not copy from userspace properly and caused a page fault. This is a kernel bug which is treated quite severely.

Hence  I am raising this issue to see if I have missed any proposed fix or is this already being worked on?
Hardware:

1. CPU details (the last processor in cat /proc/cpuinfo).

   ```
   processor   : 31     
   vendor_id   : GenuineIntel  
   cpu family  : 6.  
   model       : 79.  
   model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz.  
   stepping    : 1.  
   microcode   : 0xb000021.
   ```
2. RAM

   ```
   Memory Device.  
   Array Handle: 0x0037.  
   Error Information Handle: Not Provided.  
   Total Width: 72 bits.  
   Data Width: 64 bits.  
   Size: 16384 MB.  
   Form Factor: DIMM.  
   Set: None.  
   Locator: DIMM_A0.  
   Bank Locator: _Node0_Channel0_Dimm0.  
   Type: <OUT OF SPEC>.  
   Type Detail: Synchronous. 
   Speed: 2133 MHz.  
   Manufacturer: Samsung.  
   Serial Number: 4156465A.  
   Asset Tag: DIMM_A0_AssetTag.  
   Part Number: M393A2K40BB0-CPB     
   Rank: 1.  
   Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz.  
   Minimum voltage:  1.200 V.  
   Maximum voltage:  1.200 V.  
   Configured voltage:  1.200 V.
   ```

Comment: Some minutes ago I had a serious problem with a kernel update on a 18.04 64bit Lubuntu. I don't remember the kernel number, but now the Partition Table is lost. At the Disk Utility the whole disk is shown as _Unknown_ and the _Partitioning_ as _Not Partitioned_. I booted another disk with 12.04 32bit and I see the above, plus at the Gparted the disk with the problem does not appear at all.